# Http POST failing with status code: 406 and with status: Not Acceptable

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, apache-httpclient-4.x

I was trying to post some data to AWS EC2 rest end-point, from an AWS Lambda. I was getting response "with status code: 406 and with status: Not Acceptable". I tried fixing this, with adding accept headers as below

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serviceURL);
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "*/*");
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, "*");
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "*");
    httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, "*");
    httpPost.setEntity( new InputStreamEntity(content, ContentType.APPLICATION_XML) );
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Am i missing something? Is there anything else that i should be looking into?

Answer (score 0):

Attach exception log please. Are u trying to send this method though any kind of front

Comment: There is no exception thrown and i do not have see any helpful logs in the system. Its just that, i am receiving a 406 error from the server.